# Problem with updating NULL values in Salesforce using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, null, salesforce

I am trying to upsert the user data to salesforce using a python patch request. I have a dataset in the form of dataframe that consists of several null values. While trying to upsert the data to salesforce it throws an error that,

```
{'message': 'Deserializing the instance of date from VALUE_STRING, value nan, cannot be executed or the request is missing a required field at [line:1, column:27]', 'errorCode': 'JSON_PARSER_ERROR'}
```

To resolve the error I have tried to replace the values using None and also, Null as mentioned in the below code. Still, I receive the same error.

```
df_1.fillna(value=None,method = None,inplace=True)
df_1 = df_1.replace(np.NaN,"null")
```

The error then is :

```
{'message': 'Deserializing the instance of date from VALUE_STRING, value null, cannot be executed or the request is missing a required field at [line:1, column:27]', 'errorCode': 'JSON_PARSER_ERROR'}
```

Any possible leads would be immensely helpful

Comment: Do you know which API you're using? PATCH sounds like rest rather than soap but "normal" or bulk API?

Comment: I am using REST API

Comment: It should work when you set the data type to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find a way to inspect the final JSON generated just before it's sent out.

You can use [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) to experiment (there's "Utilities -> REST Explorer" after you log in) and over normal REST API the [update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm) is a straightforward operation

```
PATCH {your instance url}/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Account/0017000000Lg8Wh
```

(put your account id) with body (either form works)

```
{
    "BillingCity" : null,
    "BillingCountry": ""
}
```

should clear the fields. A `"null"` won't work, it counts as a string.

====

If you're using "Bulk API 2.0" (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk, I think you'd notice it's different, asynchronous dance of intialise job, upload data, start processing, periodically check "is it done yet"...) for [JSON format null should work too, for XML you need special tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_valid_records.htm) and if your format is CSV - it's supposed to be [`#N/A`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_valid_record_rows.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df.replace({np.nan: None}, inplace=True)
```

This is the equivalent of submitting a Null or Empty String value to Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Replacing NA with an empty string '' should worked for non-numeric data types, but this would throw a json parser error for the numeric fields. You can switch to:

```
import numpy as np
df.replace({np.nan: None})
```

Using Python None seems acceptable for all data types in Salesforce, at least when creating records using the SalesForce API.